# I am trying to save a user to mysql database using post request as follow, but I got the error bcrypt Error: data and hash arguments required

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Code for the user controller :

```
const { create } = require("./user.service");

const { genSaltSync, hashSync } = require("bcrypt");

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

module.exports = {

    createUser: (req, res) => {
        const body = req.body;
        const salt = genSaltSync(20);
        body.password = hashSync(body.password, salt);
        create(body, (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
                return res.status(500).json({
                    success: 0,
                    return: "Database connection error"
                });
            }
            return res.status(200).json({
                success: 1,
                data: results
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Below is the error I am getting:-

> Error: data and salt arguments required
>     at hashSync (E:\node\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:91:15)
>    at createUser (E:\node\api\users\user.controller.js:12:25)
>    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>     at next (E:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>    at Route.dispatch (E:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>    at E:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>    at Function.process_params (E:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>    at next (E:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>    at Function.handle (E:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)

Comment: Please format your code properly. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: `data and salt arguments required` on your body object.